# ASP.Net Apps hosted in IIS

Tags: asp.net, windows, sql-server-2008, session, iis-7

I hosted `ASP.NET` Apps in Windows 2008 Server. I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2 as back-end.

When I host I got the error `Apps pool error`. I modified Apps Pool setting Identity to Local Services, and it started working. I use `Session` in my website, but the `Session` expires immediately or after two minutes, not sure exactly when. The session expiration is set as 20 minitues. Why is this happening?

Below is my `connectionStrings`:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="BaOmarERPConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=IT-PC;Initial Catalog=ERP;User ID=sa;Password=1234"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="SSconstr"
         value="server=IT-PC;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;Integrated Security=SSPI;uid=sa;pwd=1234;database=ERP" />
  </appSettings>
```

Comment: Thats not related to the connection string, it must be your configuration. Have you set the application pool correctly, in first case?

Comment: Yes i set it. But why session is expired? I used the session in my project. I used session on every page load if session("Us_No")=nothing Respone.redirect("Login.aspx") end if.

Comment: Which IIS version you are using?

Comment: IIS7 on windows server 2008